# angular controller array empty even though i just defined it

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

the following is a function in an angular controller. "alert (coffee.brand)", or any other part of the array, prints "undefined," which obviously it isn't. The weird part is, undefined prints the correct number of times in the for loop, so it knows the array is populated, it just can't seem to read the data. thoughts? Thanks in advance!

```
$scope.activate = function(id){


            $scope.coffees =
    [
    {'id': 1,
    'brand': 'Folgers',
    'name': 'Regular',
    'country': 'America',
    'reviews': [
            {'rating': 3,
            'comment': "gross",
            'reviewer': "James"
            }
    ]
    },
    {'id': 2,
    'brand': 'Starbucks',
    'name': 'Mocha',
    'country': 'America',
    'reviews': [
    {'rating': 7,
    'comment': 'insane!',
    'reviewer': 'Bob'
    },
    {'rating': 5,
    'comment': 'solid...',
    'reviewer': 'Joe'
    }
    ]
    }
    ];

            for (coffee in $scope.coffees){                       

                    alert (coffee.brand);
                    if (coffee.id == id){
                            $scope.currCoffee = coffee;
                            alert("here")
                            alert ($scope.currCoffee.id);
                    }
            }

    };
```

Comment: coffee is key not the object itself, so go like `$scope.coffees[coffee]`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `for in` loop incorrectly. It does not iterate over elements in an array, but property names of an object. In your case, as you are using an implicitly numerically indexed array, it would be better to use a normal `for` loop, like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.coffees.length; i++) {        
    var coffee = $scope.coffees[i];               
    alert (coffee.brand);
    if (coffee.id == id){
        $scope.currCoffee = coffee;
        alert("here")
        alert ($scope.currCoffee.id);
    }
}
```

See the documentation over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for more information about the `for in` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the for loop to

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.coffees.length; i++) {
```

and retrieve values like

```
alert($scope.coffees[i].brand);
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/bmuJmJO94mEzGuB3uF0K?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

coffee is key not the object itself, so go like $scope.coffees[coffee].

For more information

- [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

  It iterates enumerable own and enumerable inherited properties.

Comment: why downvote.. atleast put comment so could also understand